# Download a file from Firebase using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, firebase-storage

**Thanks in Advance**
I'm trying to download a file, specifically a PDF file, from firebase using C#
And it keeps throwing the exception: **"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."**
I have tried converting the Link to a Uri, I have tried hard-coding it to  **"gs://xxxxxxx.appspot.com/PDF/MyPDF.pdf"**

**Note** The two lines added **didn't help**

What am I doing wrong

Here is the code:

```
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private async Task download( string folder, string fileName )
        {
            FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage( Bucket,
                 new FirebaseStorageOptions
                 {
                     AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(
                         fireBaseAuthLink.FirebaseToken ),
                     ThrowOnCancel = true,
                 } );

            var fileRef = storage.Child( folder ).Child( fileName );
            string link = "";
            try
            {
                link = await fileRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync();
                var info = await fileRef.GetMetaDataAsync();
                processDownload( fileName, link, (int)info.Size );
            }
            catch( Exception we )
            {
                MessageBox.Show( we.Message );
            }
        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private void processDownload( string finalFileName, string link, int size )
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( link );
                httpRequest.Method = "GET";

                // These two lines added to try to get it to work ----------------
                httpRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                httpRequest.Proxy.Credentials =
                    System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                // ---------------------------------------------------------------

                httpRequest.ContentType = "application/pdf; encoding='utf-8'";
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

                Stream httpResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

                // Define buffer and buffer size
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                int bytesRead = 0;

                // Read from response and write to file
                FileStream fileStream = File.Create( finalFileName );
                while( ( bytesRead = httpResponseStream.Read( buffer, 0, size ) ) != 0 )
                {
                    fileStream.Write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
                }
            }
            catch( WebException we )
            {
                MessageBox.Show( we.Message ); 
            }
        }
```

And The firebase rules are

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /PDF/{allPaths=**} {
           allow get;
           allow read;
           allow write;
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't the library of `FirebaseStorage` have a download method?

Comment: @LeiYang I don't know, I'm just having a break from android dev and trying out some C#

Comment: it doesn't matter what language you use. but first you must make sure you can download same url file by browser. then use devtools to insepect possible authtication http headers, which must be added to http clinet.

Comment: @LeiYang Yes, I have tried that, and the link is valid

Comment: Even though I have changed my code to answer my question, I would still like to know how to do this automatically

Comment: This URL can help you 
https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/768849/Download-file-from-FireBase-using-C-and-VBNet-in-ASPNet/

Comment: Thanks @DOTNETTeam but I get an  

    `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`   

exception on this line  

`var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;`

Answer (score 0):

**This is an alternate answer for those who don't actually want to download it**
Simply replace the line:

```
processDownload( fileName, link, (int)info.Size );
```

**WITH**

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( link );
```

This opens the PDF in your browser

Comment: try logout browser first, will the code still work?

Answer (score 0):

**Ok, after much frustration and searching I have succeeded**
**C# Experts**, please tell me what I don't need, I'm an android developer :)

Here is the answer

```
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private async Task download( string folder, string fileName )
        {
            FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage( Bucket,
                 new FirebaseStorageOptions
                 {
                     AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(
                         fireBaseAuthLink.FirebaseToken ),
                     ThrowOnCancel = true,
                 } );

            var fileRef = storage.Child( folder ).Child( fileName );
            string link = "";
            try
            {
                link = await fileRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync();
                var info = await fileRef.GetMetaDataAsync();
                processDownload( fileName, link, (int)info.Size );
            }
            catch( Exception we )
            {
                MessageBox.Show( we.Message );
            }
        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private void processDownload( string finalFileName, string link, int size )
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest =
                    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( link );

                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = 
                    (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                
                HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
                    new HttpRequest( link, link, "" ),
                    new HttpResponse( new StringWriter() )
                    );
                
                HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                response.ClearContent();
                response.Clear();
                response.ClearHeaders();
                response.Buffer = true;
                response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=\"" + finalFileName + "\"" );

                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                int bytesRead = 0;

                string userProfile = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "USERPROFILE" );
                string downloadsFolder = userProfile + "/Downloads/";
                FileStream fileStream = File.Create( downloadsFolder + finalFileName );
                Stream httpResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
                while( ( bytesRead = httpResponseStream.Read( buffer, 0, size ) ) != 0 )
                {
                    fileStream.Write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
                }
                
                fileStream.Flush();
                fileStream.Close();
                response.Flush();
                response.End();
                httpResponse.Close();
            }
            catch( WebException we )
            {
                MessageBox.Show( we.Message );
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks to everyone who helped

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what a revelation, I found this in Google Cloud Docs and modified, just a **TRITE** easier :/
"One Line to rule them All" :)

```
public void downloadFile()
{
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile( "your-json-file-from-gcp" );
    StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.Create( credential );

    // eg: Images/MyImage.jpg
    string objectName = "what-file-you-want-to-download-from-what-folder";
    
    // eg: "c://CallItSomethingElseIfYouWant.jpg"
    string localPath = "where-you-want-to-store-it-AND-call-it";
    
    // eg: xxxxxxxx-xxxxx.appspot.com
    string bucketName = "xxxxxxxx-xxxxx.appspot.com";
    
    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite( @localPath );

    // --- The Magic Line
    storageClient.DownloadObject( bucketName, objectName, fileStream );
    // --  

    fileStream.Flush();
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I don't know what you edited, but thanks