# How to get all images from FirebaseStorage in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, storage

I want to get all images I have saved in my storage folder. There is a way to get the Metadata and the Downloadlink for only one image. But what if I want the download links for all of my images?

My small code so far:

```
try
{
    FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage("*****.appspot.com");
    var info =  await storage.Child("reports").Child($"{public_id}").Child("report_picture_01.png").GetDownloadUrlAsync();
    var starsRef = storage.Child("reports").Child($"{public_id}").Child("report_picture_01.png");
    string link = await starsRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync();
 
    MessageBox.Show(info.ToString());
}

catch (FirebaseStorageException ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
```

Similar questions:

- [How to get all images stored in firebase storage folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67003663/how-to-get-all-images-stored-in-firebase-storage-folder)
- [Download a file from Firebase using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71233857/download-a-file-from-firebase-using-c-sharp)

It exist one possible solution: You rename all your image files with numbers and then you ilerate throught your folder and look if theres any files named like the numbers. But is there a smarter and faster way to solve this problem?

I've tried serveral methods for it and it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried [list all files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files) it first then getting downloadURIs through looping on listed objects.check this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56402109/18265638) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73786924/18265638) which might help

Comment: I'm using WPF and Visual Studio 22. There are only inofficial libarys which provide a API for Firebase. Unluckly those librarys doesn't provide any "List" or "ListAll" methods :(